# Marking clocksource 'tsc-early' as unstable because the skew is too large: and Time drift on ubuntu server 22.04.4 LTS

Tags: server, time, clock

I have an Ubuntu Server with this config

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
Linux lab01 6.5.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Mar 12 10:22:43 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and I've a serious issue with the clock that is unable to keep the time by its own. It drift a lot and once, it checks to an NTP server, it corrects its time basically having the time of the server drifting into the future to being brought back once a new time is delivered by an online NTP server.

```
I've notice that there's some issues with the clocksource

lab@lab01:~$ sudo dmesg | grep clocksource
[sudo] password for lab:
[    0.026856] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
[    0.100958] clocksource: tsc-early: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x2c9485be866, max_idle_ns: 440795258057 ns
[    0.106744] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.146577] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc-early
[    1.765438] clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU1: Marking clocksource 'tsc-early' as unstable because the skew is too large:
[    1.765440] clocksource:                       'refined-jiffies' wd_nsec: 512032000 wd_now: fffedc08 wd_last: fffedb88 mask: ffffffff
[    1.765442] clocksource:                       'tsc-early' cs_nsec: 852454992 cs_now: 9bda08539 cs_last: 9207bcdc0 mask: ffffffffffffffff
[    1.765443] clocksource:                       Clocksource 'tsc-early' skewed 340422992 ns (340 ms) over watchdog 'refined-jiffies' interval of 512032000 ns (512 ms)
[    1.765445] clocksource:                       'tsc-early' is current clocksource.
[    1.765448] tsc: Marking TSC unstable due to clocksource watchdog
[    1.985248] clocksource: Switched to clocksource refined-jiffies
```

Could it be an issue linked to the clock? How I fix it